# Why does dropdown menu not appear below its container using overflow:hidden css in its container element?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that the submenu of my drop down menu is not appearing beyond its container element, when the drop down menu is shown. 
In the code I have main menu and sub-menu items. The main menu items are : HOME, ABOUT, SERVICES, PRODUCTS and CONTACT. And the submenu items for each main menu items are: A,B,C,D and E. I want the sub menu items to appear below each main menu items. The sub menu items appear only when I increase the padding of the main menu items so that the main menu container is in the background of the sub menu items. They donot appear otherwise. Here is my code :

```css
.menu{
 width: 100%;
 background: #d80000;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 10px;
}
.menu .mainmenu{
 margin-left: -40px;
 /*display: none;*/ 
}

.menu .mainmenu .heading{
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin-right: 1px;
}
.menu .mainmenu .heading a{
 background: #fff;
 padding: 8px 100px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #d80000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.menu .mainmenu .heading a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
}
.menu:hover .mainmenu{
 display: block;
}
.heading{
 position: relative;
}
.submenu{
 display: none;
 background: #d80000;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 margin-left: -40px;
}
.submenu .items{
 display: block;
}
.submenu .items a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.heading:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
}
.submenu .items a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}

li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a 
{
    background: #d80000;
}

li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #d80000;
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #d80000;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="menu">
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href=#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href=#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href=#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href=#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href=#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href=#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The expected result is to show the sub menu to drop down and appear below the main menu items as we hover on each of the main menu items but it is not happening in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `overflow: hidden;` in your **.menu** class.

If you remove this line, your submenu will be show.

you could use another class to control float.

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

and append after your last `<li>`:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be the problem. I have also posted the corrected code and also used flex to avoid  float related mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check [codepen](https://codepen.io/romiul/full/xMdxmP)

```
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="mainmenu">
            <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                    <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element is taller than the element containing it, and it is floated, it will overflow outside of its container.
Fix this problem with the code:

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

See working example:
https://codepen.io/juditp/pen/KJmKjM

Comment: thanks for the code. helped to get the result. I also found that the issue was the overflow hidden and the stacking up was due to missing clearfix class. I was able to fix the code after studying your codepen code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of `<a href=#">` which is missing a quote mark.  it should be `<a href="#">` instead

Comment: That could have been the problem also. I found that overflow:hidden was the problem which caused the submenu to not display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I am positing the final code after removing all the errors in the above code.

Important points:

- I have used display:flex instead of float left
- As float is not used, there is no clearfix class. This has helped in showing the submenu without stacking upwards.
- I have removed overflow:hidden in the original code which seemed to be the main reason for hiding the drop down menu,

This answer is just to update the wrong code posted above by me to corrected code.

```css
.menu{
 background: #d80000;
 width: 100%;
 padding:10px 10px;
}

.mainmenu{
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
}

.mainmenu .heading{
 margin-right: 2px;
 
}


.mainmenu .heading a{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #d80000;
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.submenu{
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}

.heading a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
}

.heading:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
 margin-left: -40px;
}

.submenu .items a{
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 1px solid #d80000;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style4.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```